# excel: Find a word in a cell from a list of word then return that word

Tags: excel

I want to extract the matching word form worksheet 1 in another worksheet. 
In worksheet 1 I have a list of words (B1:B2266) like car, red, windows, etc. 
On worksheet 2 I have a list of sentences (C2:C24068) like the car is red, the car have 3 windows, etc.

What I'm trying to do is to create a column in worksheet 2 that returns the words that are contained in any sentence present in column C from column B. It would be even better to create one column for each word that is present from column B in each sentence. So for example in the sentence "the car have 3 windows" I want to have at least 2 cells at the side, one with the word card and next to it in a different cell the word windows.

I searched this question on the forum, but the're only similar questions, related more to numbers instead of words. I hope that someone could help me.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where did you get stuck?

Comment: It looks like you are new here. Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read this article, it will get you better answers and reduce frustration: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I tried =INDEX(Sheet1!B:B,AGGREGATE(15,7,ROW(Sheet1!B:B)/(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(Sheet1!B:B,Sheet1!C2))),1))

Comment: Please edit the question to add details. Use code blocks to separate code from text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not pretty but I gave it a shot:

Excel file: https://gofile.io/?c=N2WyZN

It has limitations though, as you will see in the example I set it up for a maximum of an 8 word sentence, but of course you can expand this.

Also, this task might be best suited for a VBA script.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks buddy, that solved the problem. Is there an advantage to do it via  VBA script instead of a function?

Comment: Well, since I didn't provide a one liner and had to rely on several columns for the calculations, in my mind I can see it simplified by code.

Comment: I would gladly try it if you make it.

Answer (score 0):

If one has the Dynamic Array formula FILTER:

```
=TRANSPOSE(FILTER(Sheet1!$B$1:$B$2266,ISNUMBER(SEARCH(Sheet1!$B$1:$B$2266,C2))))
```

Comment: Hi buddy, this is giving me a 0 value as a result. Some cells contain the word article, so sometimes lets say the cell could be "der Bibliothek" but still I know that the deck contains sentences that match that entire cell.